# How to disable keyboard's ContextMenu function with javascript in webpage on chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, contextmenu

i would like to disable 'contextmenu' from keyboard key that is called 'menukey'. the key code is 93.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.which == 93) {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

I've tested the above code on some browser application :

✔ IE 10

✔ firefox 22

✔ Opera 12.16

✘ Chrome 28.0.1500.95

**?** Safari x.x

> ✔ succeed | ✘ not worked | **?** not tested

is there any guys who can fix?
why it's on chrome does not work?

Comment: Why do you want to disable the context menu?

Comment: @icktoofay just for disabling. can you help?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I can help, but I'm curious why you want to do it; most of the time people who want to do this do it to prevent users from viewing the source or getting an image URL, but usually there's a trivial workaround.

Comment: Your reason for disabling is "just for disabling"? Well that clears that up.

Comment: @icktoofay yeah, that's the reason. I've disabled Ctrl + U, Ctrl + Shift + I, and right mouse click. but the problem is on chrome it can occur using the contextmenu-key on the keyboard.

Comment: @HerryKusmadi Anybody can still view the source code: fiddle, firebug, dev tools...  If you wanted to add your own context menu, that would make more sense

Comment: Herry, even with everything you've disabled the user can still use the main menu's View Source option. (In Chrome that is under the Tools; the other dev tools can be opened from there too.)

Comment: @nnnnnn just for the casual visitor/reader. :D not geek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the method you're using doesn't work, but you can do this instead:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
    return false;
};
```

Comment: `contextmenu` is the most correct event, since it's an abstraction of all the ways they can be displayed. You don't need all the other code  (Ctrl + U, Ctrl + Shift + I, and right mouse click. )with this, I believe.

Comment: i think, this is same with <body oncontextmenu="return false">.  but, your code above, worked on right-mouse-click & keyboard's contextmenu..

Comment: Yes, that should have the same effect.

Comment: Events passed to the "contextmenu" event are always of type "MouseEvent", opening the contextmenu with the contextmenukey or the right mousebutton, results in both having the property `e.which` set to 3,
how do you distinguish if it was a keypress? Except for the `e.x` and `e.y` being set to `1` in case of the keypress

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 - This code doesn't distinguish. But although the question itself just asks about the key, the OP's comments above indicate that they're actually trying to completely disable the context menu, so...

Comment: @nnnn not same effect. previously, i've used on <body> tag. this is why i make question that not worked on chrome browser.

Comment: OK. Well I wouldn't recommend an inline html attribute event handler anyway. What I've shown in my answer worked for me in Chrome.

Comment: @nnnnnn Woops, i have missed the comment, saying everything else was disabled as well

Comment: Yes this totally works on chrome to disable the contextmenu completely

Answer (score 2):

You could

1. Create a flag if the key was pressed
2. Add an "keydown" EventListener

   - store if the user pressed the contextmenu key,
3. Add an "contextmenu" EventListener

   - if the key was pressed
   - Prevent the default action
   - set the flag to false

---

```
var keypressed = false;
window.addEventListener ("keydown",function (e) { 
   if (e.keyCode === 93) keypressed = true;
});

window.addEventListener ("contextmenu",function (e) {
    if (keypressed) {
         e.preventDefault(e);
         keypressed = false;
    }
})
```

The idea is to hide the contextmenu only on the key pressed, as the title indicates, but still allows it on mouseclicks etc.

If you want to completely disable it, go for @nnnnnn's Answer instead =)

Heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Df9e7/)
<sub>Only tested in Chrome 29</sub>

Comment: Isn't this kind of complicated? Or is the idea to still allow the context menu from the mouse but not the keyboard? From the OP's comments above they don't seem to want the context menu at all.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes the idea is to still show the contextmenu on a mousepress, the title says "How to disable keyboard's ContextMenu function" at least =)

Comment: Cool. +1. Either way my understanding is that the OP's underlying goal is to stop the user from viewing the page source, which can't be done anyway.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks, Yes you seem to be totally right about the OP's goal =), so +1 for yours' too, nevertheless, future visiting people coming here by googling "How to disable keyboard's ContextMenu", may actually want to do what the question is indicating =)

Answer (score 0):

Disable full keyboard without tab:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
       return false;
    }
};
```